# Data type of memory address

Tags: c, pointers

I have a function where I want to return the memory address of another function. What would be the proper return type?

```
void func1 (int n, int y);
char* str_func(const char* n);

ptr_type (void)
{
    // function
}
```

My first thought was `void *` or `intptr_t`, but I don't think that's the correct type as what is located at that location is a function (or label, or something else).

Comment: Can you give an example of a function whose address you'd like to return?

Comment: It will be a type like `int (*)()`, but need more code details.  Post the "another function".

Comment: If its a function, perhaps a function pointer?

Comment: "The address of a function" is the definition of "function pointer".  There are as many types of these as there are function signatures -- more actually. Formally, they are not compatible with any object pointer type, including `void *`, and it is not guranteed that function pointer values can be converted to `intptr_t` without data loss.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica it could be any function, I just want to have something that can basically take a string name and return the address of that function -- whatever the function prototype is.

Comment: @samuelbrody1249 any prototype may be a bit more troublesome. Perhaps you could make every function that can be returned by this function have a prototype like `void *foo(void *param)`. I believe that is something like what `pthread` does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a function where I want to return the memory address of another function. What would be the proper return type?

The proper return type depends on the functions whose addresses you want to return, and on what you want the caller to be able to do with them.  If you only cared about returning the addresses, not doing anything with them, then any function pointer type will do, but you will have to cast.  For example,

```
typedef void (*func_ptr)(void);

func_ptr get_func_pointer(void) {
    return (func_ptr) str_func;
}
```

But using some random function type does not provide for *calling* the function.  The pointer must be cast back to a function pointer type compatible with the pointed-to function before it can be used to call that function, and the caller somehow needs to know what that is in order to do so:

```
    typedef char * (*str_func_ptr)(const char* n);

    str_func_ptr p = (str_func_ptr) get_func_pointer();
    p("argument");
```

Under most circumstances, it is better to have the function return a function pointer of the correct type in the first place. Of course, such a function is suitable only for returning pointers to functions having the chosen signature.

Also, I reiterate my comment that formally, function pointers are not compatible with any object pointer type, including `void *`.  The language specification does not provide for converting function pointers to type `void *`, and although it does permit converting them to integer types such as `intptr_t`, it does not provide a sound basis for relying on any such conversions to be lossless.

Finally, I observe that the code above could have been written without the `typedef`s, but it would have been much messier.

Comment: thanks, actually I was just curious and it was more a low-level question (sort of like jumping to a label in assembly), I don't think there's an actual C correlate to it, but this is a great answer thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the type of the function you want to return.  A pointer to `func1` would have type `void (*)(int, int)` - "pointer to function taking two `int` parameters and returning `void`".  You would declare a pointer *variable* of this type as

```
void (*p)(int, int) = func1;
```

If you want to declare a function returning that type, you’d just replace `p` with the function prototype:

```
void (*   p     )(int, int);
          |
       +––+––––+
       |       |
       v       v
void (*foo(void))(int, int);

void (*foo(void))(int, int)
{
  return func1;
}
```

The declaration reads as

```
       foo                   –– foo is
       foo(    )             –– a function taking
       foo(void)             ––   no parameters
      *foo(void)             –– returning a pointer to
     (*foo(void))(        )  ––   a function taking
     (*foo(void))(        )  ––     unnamed parameter is
     (*foo(void))(int     )  ––     int
     (*foo(void))(int,    )  ––     unnamed parameter is
     (*foo(void))(int, int)  ––     int
void (*foo(void))(int, int)  ––   returning void
```

You could create a `typedef` for `func1`'s type (we’ll call it `func1_t`) and return a pointer to that:

```
typedef void func1_t(int, int);

func1_t *foo( void )
{
  return func1;
}
```

I would *strongly* discourage hiding pointers behind `typedef`s - IME they create maintenance problems.

If you want to return a pointer to `str_func`, you would write

```
char *(*foo(void))(const char *)
{
  return str_func;
}
```

which reads as

```
        foo                          –– foo is
        foo(    )                    –– a function taking
        foo(void)                    ––   no parameters
       *foo(void)                    –– returning a pointer to
      (*foo(void))(            )     ––   a function taking
      (*foo(void))(            )     ––     unnamed parameter is
      (*foo(void))(           *)     ––     a pointer to
      (*foo(void))(const char *)     ––       const char
     *(*foo(void))(const char *)     ––  returning a pointer to
char *(*foo(void))(const char *)     ––    char
```

Again, you could create a typedef for `str_func`s type and return a pointer to that:

```
typedef char *str_func_t(const char *);

str_func_t *foo(void)
{
  return str_func;
}
```

Comment: thanks for this -- why would the second one be `(*foo(void))` and not just `(*foo)`?

Comment: @samuelbrody1249:  Because just `(*foo)` is not a function declaration - it just declares a pointer variable.